# difference between text_field and text_area in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have seen examples of text_field and text_area being used in forms like this:

```
<%= form_for :account do |a| %>
    Name: <%= a.text_field :name %><br />
    Password: <%= a.text_area :password %><br />
    Password Confirmation: <%= a.text_field :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= a.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I don't understand the difference, though. Is it necessary for a beginner Rails developer to understand the difference?

I found some explanations in the API which I don't understand - perhaps somebody can take a look and let me know what is going on.

For "text_area":

```
text_area(object_name, method, options = {})

Returns a textarea opening and closing tag set tailored for accessing a 
specified attribute (identified by method) on an object assigned to the template 
(identified by object). 
 Additional options on the input tag can be passed as a hash with options.
```

Then, for "text_field":

```
  text_field(object_name, method, options = {}) Link

    Returns an input tag of the “text” type tailored for accessing a specified 
attribute (identified by method) on an object assigned to the template 
(identified by object). Additional options on the input tag can be passed 
as a hash with options. These options will be tagged onto the HTML as an 
HTML element attribute as in the example shown.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a.text_field :name` is parse to the following html

`<input type="text" name="name">`

`a.text_area :name` would parse to something like:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">

</textarea>
```

depending on the options passed.

The simplest way of looking at it is `text_field` gives you a place for a single line of text, where text_area gives an area for multiple lines.

you can pass a hash of options to the `text_area` helper to specify the number of rows and columns.

In the example you give above, it would be poor practice to use either `text_field` or `text_area` for passwords, you'd be better to use `a.password_field`

Comment: how do you recommend I make a field for a boolean column? I tried making a checkbox with `Private? <%= a.check_box :private %>` but it didn't work.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box Checkboxes are more complicated  I've blogged on select boxes, but the principles are the same http://www.fmhcc.com.au/ruby/rails/using-collection_select-in-rails/

Answer (score 0):

thats a good answer - funny when googling this and looking for a spot on example - after i read the response above - i looked at my code and realized it was an even better example

```
 <%= f.label :name %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
 <%= f.label :bio %>
 <%= f.text_area :bio %><br />
```

makes sense, name would only need a single line (unless you have a super long name) where as bio, would need multiple lines.